# rsync failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync

I am trying to use "rsync" to copy file to another machine.
This is the command I am trying:

```
sudo rsync -avztP --delete --recursive --inplace /folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile someuser@192.168.1.100:/backup/files -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

I am getting this error:

```
sending incremental file list
file1
    25728640 100%    15.38MB/s    0:00:02 (total: 100%) (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)
rsync: open "/folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

```
sent 25736406 bytes  received 31 bytes  2258914.96 bytes/sec
total size is 25728640  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1355) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Here are the permissions of the local machine:

```
ls -ld / /folder1 /folder1/folder2/ /folder1/folder2/folder3/ /folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile

drwxr-xr-x  26 root  root      4096 Jul 25 23:00 /
drwxr-xr-x  25 root  root      4096 Sep 16 23:37 /folder1
drwxrwxrwx+ 12 root  root      4096 Feb 29  2020 /folder1/folder2/
drwxrwxrwx+  2 admin users     4096 May  4  2019 /folder1/folder2/folder3/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 admin users 25728640 May  4  2019 /folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile
```

And the permissions on the remote machine:

```
ls -ld / /backup /backup/files/

drwxr-xr-x 20 root root  26 Sep  5 21:25 /
drwxr-xr-x  3 root users  3 Sep 13 02:07 /backup
drwxrwsr-x  2 root root   2 Sep 13 02:07 /backup/files/
```

Linux on local machine: Linux DiskStation 3.10.105

Linux on remote machine: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Linux 5.4.0-47-generic x86_64.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What linux version?  Check SELinux on target machine.

Comment: The error is about not being able to open the file on the source machine. Are you sure I should check the target machine?

Comment: The target machine linux is: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Linux 5.4.0-47-generic x86_64. The source machine is: Linux DiskStation 3.10.105

Comment: This is "ls -ld /backup/files/" on the remote target. Please note it doesn't have "file1" yet, since it was never rsynced:
drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 2 Sep 13 02:07 /backup/files/

Comment: This is the "ls" on the source:
drwxr-xr-x  26 root  root      4096 Jul 25 23:00 /
drwxr-xr-x  25 root  root      4096 Sep 16 23:37 /some
drwxrwxrwx+ 12 root  root      4096 Feb 29  2020 /some/folder/
drwxrwxrwx+  2 admin users     4096 May  4  2019 /some/folder/folder2/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 admin users 15728640 May  4  2019 /some/folder/folder2/file

Comment: please note I masked the name of the folders and file. So folders are called: "some", "folder", "folder2" and the file is called: "file"

Comment: I updated the info. Please let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: @roaima I update the info. Please let me know if you still see inconsistencies..

Comment: Thanks. Should be fixed now..

Comment: That's much better thank you. Is the remote user `root`?

Comment: Indeed, I assume the remote user is root since it is the main (and only) user I created when installing Ubuntu..

Comment: @roaima, is there a problem with the remote use being root?

Comment: If the remote user _is not_ root then that's probably your problem. Furthermore, given the error message I would be surprised if it was root

Answer (score 3):

I know this topic is quite old but I had the same problem a few days before and I fixed it by removing the "--inplace" option.